# Will this CSS work across mulitple devices for a web application?

Tags: css

I needed my three tab content areas to be the same height so I used the following CSS to achieve this.

```
#BasicDetails, #Tracking, #ProjectEvaluationReport {
                height: 30pc;               
            }
```

On desktop monitors this works just as I needed to. The user potentially might want the web application to be be accessible through mobile and tablet devices, so would my CSS still hold as it should?

I tried the following JQuery

```
<script>
        $("#tabs").tabs().css({
            'min-height': '400px',
            'overflow': 'auto'
        });
    </script>
```

but couldn't get this working for my tabs, though as I said 30pc worked exactly as I needed it to.

Comment: use media queries for responsive design. check them here ->https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 1):

`pc` (pica) is a CSS unit intended for print stylesheets.

- 1 pc is defined as 12pt
- 1pt is defined at 1/72 of an inch
- 1 inch in CSS is defined as 96dpi

> The unit in doesn't represent a physical inch on screen, but represents 96px. That means that whatever is the real screen pixel density, it is assumed to be 96dpi. On devices with a greater pixel density, 1in will be smaller than 1 physical inch. Similarly mm, cm, and pt are not absolute length.

[MDN: CSS units and dots-per-inch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#CSS_units_and_dots-per-inch)

This means that the actual height of your elements while vary, depending of the pixel density of the device ("retina/non-retina" and so on).